# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as a server for client

Tags: c#

Can I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as a server? when I deploy the Windows Form application on his computer.

Comment: SSMS is **only** a GUI management tool - it is **NOT** a database engine that can act as a "server" - for that, you need the SQL Server **database engine**

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. SQL Server Management Studio is only used to view and manage SQL Server databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio is client software. You probably want to install SQL Server Express to act as a database server. But you can manage it with SSMS